# SSIS package hangs on Setting Source Connection

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that has been executing successfully for the last 7 years.

All of a sudden the package won't run and hangs at the Setting Source Connection step and has to be closed down via End Task.  I can access all of the databases but cannot run this package.
I believe one of our helpdesk admins may have messed something up when setting up the backup jobs on our backupexec server.

Can anyone give me some help as to what the cause could be?  I have understood it to be a permissions error, but I am not clear where that could be.

Answer (score 0):

In the SSIS package, locate the Connection Manager for the DB you are trying to connect to.  On the properties panel of that connection manager, set the 'Persist Connection' property to TRUE.  This will maintain an active connection to the database server through the entire life of the package instead of only creating a connection for a specific task.  It's a long shot, but worth a try.